# Is there any way to include variables inside strings for printing in Actionscript3?

Tags: actionscript-3, printing

I find myself always typing something like

```
Alert.show("blah = " + blah);
```

In PHP we have

```
"blah = $blah"
```

In Ruby we have

```
"blah = #{blah}"
```

Do we have anything like that in Actionscript3?

Also...what is the proper name for what we are doing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking whether you can include a variable name within a string and have it evaluated as opposed to treated like a literal (like your PHP example), the answer is no. This isn't a feature of the ActionScript language. However, you can achieve something like this by using the StringUtil's substitute method. Here's an example:

```
StringUtil.substitute("My name is {0} and I am {1} years old", name, age);
```

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/utils/StringUtil.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean the `trace()` function:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/package.html#trace()

As in:

```
trace("Blah: " + Blah);
```

Comment: it doesn't matter the function using the string.  i am just wondering if there is a way to include variables inside the actual string to avoid +

Comment: Ahhh, no I'm pretty sure there is no such functionality in ActionScript 3.